# Add somthing custom to SiteSetting

Tags: site-settings

I need to add custom section of settings in SharePoint site collection's `Site Settings`.

How can I do it?

Comment: You mean, how to add a link to your page in Site Settings ?

Comment: basically yeah, the question is not 100% clear, what the writer means :)

Answer (score 6):

To achieve that:

Add an empty element item to your project. Then add the following code to the `Elements.xml` file.

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<CustomActionGroup
Id="TestCustomGroupId"
Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.SiteSettings"
Title="Custom Site Settings Group"
Sequence="100"
Description=""
ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/<Projectpath>/<icon.gif>" />

<CustomAction
  Id="TestCustomActionId"
  GroupId="TestCustomGroupId"
  Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.SiteSettings"
  Rights="ManageWeb"
  Sequence="1"
  Title="Custom Site Settings"
  Description="Description">
      <UrlAction Url="~site/_layouts/your custom page path" /> 
</CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

3. If you need your page to have access through the top-level site context,
   replace `~site` with `~sitecollection`.
4. The `Rights="ManageWeb"` setting specifies that only users with admin level will have access to your page. For a list of possible values to add to the "Rights" attribute ,

Answer (score 2):

Basically to add some custom settings for a site you can use a SPWeb = SPSite.RootWeb ( property bag to store there settings (key, value). SPWeb.Properties

Other way is that you can store some info in web.config, but i would not advise doing that.

Other way as it was already said try using the custom list for properties.

And the last check out the [SPPersistedObject](http://joelblogs.co.uk/2010/10/10/persisting-configuration-data-in-sharepoint-2010-with-sppersistedobject/) class, which helps you to store some settings, and persist it to the database, they will also be backed up etc.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

if you would like to build something like system settings (key,value) the you can create a sharepoint list to hold the required settings.

if your question mean having page like the pages inside the sitesettings page the you can do it by creating application page and custom action to add link inside the site settings page to link to your application page